# root classes in linqpad

Tags: root, linqpad, nested-class

Classes defined in LinqPad are nested, inner classes of UserQuery. Is there a way to declare classes that are root classes?

Answer (score 11):

From version 2.4 / 4.4, you can create root classes in LINQPad by defining the `NONEST` symbol (in **C# Program** mode):

```
#define NONEST
void Main()
{
    typeof (Foo).FullName.Dump();   // Foo
}

class Foo
{
}
```

If you define a static class (which C# does not allow fo be nested), you don't need the NONEST symbol - LINQPad will extract your nested class automatically.

Comment: It appears it also does this when a static class is defined that has extension methods attached one of the other nested types.  Is this intentional?

Answer (score -1):

Select 'C# Program' as the language type in the newer versions.

Comment: The classes defined under this mode are implemented as nested classes, which is the frustration of the OP.